# Is the config file name "quartz.config" fixed (means hard-code, cannot be changed)?

Tags: c#, configuration, web-config, quartz.net

I know that Quartz.Net has several ways to loads it configuration upon startup: (from http://jvilalta.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-does-quartznet-configuration-work.html )

1. The hosting application’s configuration file
2. A file specified in an environment variable
3. The quartz.config file
4. The embedded configuration file

*Notice the quartz.config file.*

**My question:**

1. Is the config file name "quartz.config" fixed (means hard-code,
   cannot be changed)?
2. If no, how can I change it? e.g. I want to read from
   FinancialQuartz.config instead of quartz.config.
3. If no option to change the name "quartz.config". How can I specify
   when to read from FinancialQuartz.config or
   CalculationQuartz.config? (I have no real scenario for this
   question, just wonder)

Regards,

Answer (score 4):

I'm confused.

In DotNet.  You can point the app.config or web.config file to your file of choice, like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>


    <configSections>
        <section name="quartz" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.5000.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        </sectionGroup>

    </configSections>

    <quartz configSource="MyQuartzSettings.config" />
```

And "MyQuartzSettings.config" looks something like this (one example of many)

```
<quartz>

    <add key="quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.type" value="Quartz.Plugin.Xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin" />
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="DefaultQuartzScheduler" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="10" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadPriority" value="2" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold" value="60000" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.RAMJobStore, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames" value="Quartz_Jobs_001.xml" />
    <add key="quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.failOnFileNotFound" value="true" />
    <add key="quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.scanInterval" value="120" />

</quartz>
```

Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: I understand your answer, but I meant that if you do not state anything related to quartz in application config file. Quartz Scheduler will try to load config from "quartz.config". My question is that can the default name "quartz.config" be changed to anything else?

Comment: You need to specify a file name for "   <quartz configSource="MyQuartzSettings.config" />"  (the configSource).  You can specify anything you want.   This is dotNet functionality (in regards to configuration  in files), not specific to quartz.net

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer given by @granadaCoder, you can also set the quartz.config environment variable to the name of the file you want to load. Note that the configSource attribute is not quartz.net specific but a feature of the .Net framework: [SectionInformation.ConfigSource Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource.aspx)

Comment: Ok...that's also good to know.  That seems very java'esque.  And I've been br@inw@shed by MS for too long!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's fixed now. But there's a workaround for it.

Read the configuration from other ways into a `System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection`.

```cs
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddIniFile("someotherfile.ini", false, true);

var config = builder.Build();

var quartzProperties = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
foreach (var p in config.GetSection("Quartz").GetChildren().AsEnumerable())
{
    quartzProperties.Add(p.Key, p.Value);
}

IScheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory(quartzProperties).GetScheduler();
scheduler.Start();
```

Comment: Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in order to reply with full answers.